# jPaginate - Help Determining Which Page was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery's jPaginate plugin to sort data on one of my websites. The problem I am having is determining which page was click on jPaginate. I have posted my code below.

This code loads the plugin on Document Ready.

```
$("#demo2").paginate({
                        count         : a,
                        start         : 1,
                        display     : 10,
                        border                    : false,
                        text_color              : '#888',
                        background_color        : '#EEE',    
                        text_hover_color          : 'black',
                        cookies : true,
                        onChange                : function(){alert(); console.log($(this))},
                        background_hover_color    : '#CFCFCF'
                });
```

See screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/SbxHjn7H

The problem is I need to know what page was clicked whenever the user clicks on a number 1-5.. Any help or further understanding of this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to figure this out on my own..

You need to get the current page by writing a function to fire on the 'onChange' event within the jPaginate plugin.

```
$("#demo2").paginate({
                  count         : a,
                  start         : '<?=intval($page + 1);?>',
                  display     : 10,
                  border                    : false,
                  text_color              : '#888',
                  background_color        : '#EEE',    
                  text_hover_color          : 'black',
                  cookies : true,
                  onChange                : function(){

                            var getPage = $('.jPag-current').html();
                            var minusPage = getPage - 1;

                        },
                        background_hover_color    : '#CFCFCF'
                });
```